# Simplest method for applying NFC trigger to basic timer application (Android)

Tags: android, nfc

I have a basic countdown app that counts down from 10 secs when button is clicked. What would be the simplest method to have the timer start when contact is made with a specific NFC tag? (NTAG203)

I've read several NFC tutorials and the only one I've been able to get to work has been a simple tag reader. If I wanted to have a specific NFC tag trigger a simple timer app just like a button would, how would I go about doing so? Would it be best to try to read the ID or just interpret plain text as an identifier?

Thanks (Using Android Studio)

NFC app Main Activity (Code taken from this tutorial: http://shaikhhamadali.blogspot.com/2013/10/near-field-communication-nfc-android.html

```
    package com.example.nfctest2.nfctest2app;

    import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.PendingIntent;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.IntentFilter;
    import android.content.IntentFilter.MalformedMimeTypeException;
    import android.nfc.NdefMessage;
    import android.nfc.NdefRecord;
    import android.nfc.NfcAdapter;
    import android.nfc.Tag;
    import android.nfc.tech.Ndef;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public static final String MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN = "text/plain";
public static final String TAG = "NfcTut";

private TextView tV_ReadNFC;
private NfcAdapter nfcAdapt;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //initialize control
    tV_ReadNFC = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tV_ReadNFC);
    //initialise nfc adapter
    nfcAdapt = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    //check is NFC adapter initialized null when device doesn't support NFC
    if (nfcAdapt == null) {
        // device deosn't support nfc
        Toast.makeText(this, "your device doesn't support NFC.",      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
        return;
    }
    //check is NFC adapter feature enabled
    if (!nfcAdapt.isEnabled()) {
        tV_ReadNFC.setText("NFC is disabled.");
    } else {
        tV_ReadNFC.setText(R.string.attachNFCToRead);
    }
    handleIntent(getIntent());
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {

    //Call this before onPause, to avoid an IllegalArgumentException.
    stopForegroundDispatch(this, nfcAdapt);
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {

    handleIntent(intent);
}

private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
    //get action from intent
    String action = intent.getAction();
    //is action matches the NDEF_DISCOVERED
    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
        //what is the mime type
        String type = intent.getType();
        //is text plain or not
        if (MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN.equals(type)) {
            //create tag instance and retrieve extended data from intent
            Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
            //execute background task
            new NdefReaderBgTask().execute(tag);

        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "mime type is not text/plain: " + type);
        }
    }
    //is action matches the ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED
    else if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {

        // In case we would still use the Tech Discovered Intent
        Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
        //get the available technologies
        String[] techList = tag.getTechList();
        //get class name
        String searchedTech = Ndef.class.getName();

        for (String tech : techList) {
            //tag matched then execute background task
            if (searchedTech.equals(tech)) {
                new NdefReaderBgTask().execute(tag);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * @param act The corresponding {@link Activity} requesting the foreground dispatch.
 * @param adp The {@link NfcAdapter} used for the foreground dispatch.
 */
public static void requestForegroundDispatch(final Activity act, NfcAdapter adp) {
    //create instance of intent
    final Intent intent = new Intent(act.getApplicationContext(), act.getClass());
    //set flags on top
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    //crate instance of pending intent
    final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(act.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
    //create intent filters array
    IntentFilter[] filters = new IntentFilter[1];
    //create 2D array of techlist String
    String[][] techList = new String[][]{};

    // Note: This is the same filter as in our manifest.
    filters[0] = new IntentFilter();
    filters[0].addAction(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
    filters[0].addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    try {
        //add data type
        filters[0].addDataType(MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN);
    } catch (MalformedMimeTypeException e) {
        //throw exception on different mime type
        throw new RuntimeException("Check your mime type.");
    }
    //enable foreground dispatch to current activity
    adp.enableForegroundDispatch(act, pendingIntent, filters, techList);
}


public static void stopForegroundDispatch(final Activity act, NfcAdapter adp) {
    adp.disableForegroundDispatch(act);
}


private class NdefReaderBgTask extends AsyncTask<Tag, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Tag... params) {
        Tag tag = params[0];

        Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);
        if (ndef == null) {
            // when NDEF is not supported by this Tag.
            return null;
        }
        //Get the NdefMessage that was read from the tag at discovery time.
        NdefMessage ndefMessage = ndef.getCachedNdefMessage();
        //Get the NDEF Records inside this NDEF Message.
        NdefRecord[] records = ndefMessage.getRecords();
        for (NdefRecord ndefRecord : records) {
            if (ndefRecord.getTnf() == NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN && Arrays.equals(ndefRecord.getType(), NdefRecord.RTD_TEXT)) {
                try {
                    return readNDEFRecordText(ndefRecord);
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Unsupported Encoding", e);
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    private String readNDEFRecordText(NdefRecord record) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        // get record pay load variable length
        byte[] payload = record.getPayload();

        // Get the Text Encoding
        String textEncoding = ((payload[0] & 128) == 0) ? "UTF-8" : "UTF-16";

        // Get the Language Code
        int languageCodeLength = payload[0] & 0063;

        // String languageCode = new String(payload, 1, languageCodeLength, "US-ASCII");
        // e.g. "en"

        // Get the Text
        return new String(payload, languageCodeLength + 1, payload.length - languageCodeLength - 1, textEncoding);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (result != null) {
            tV_ReadNFC.setText("Content in your TAG: " + result);
        }
    }
}
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the foreground dispatch to receive the NFC event is a good start.

Identifying a specific tag very much depends on what you need in your context:

1. You could match tag IDs. This is certainly the easiest approach as every tag exposes some ID that is used by the NFC device during tag enumeration and anti-collision. However, this approach has some limitations:

   - Not all tags expose static IDs. Some tags generate a fresh random ID upon power-up. Identifying such a tag from its ID is therefore impossible.
   - Depending on the protocol, IDs may have different lengths. E.g. an ISO 14443A (`NfcA`) tag may have a 4-byte, 7-byte or 10-byte UID. Thus, you have to consider this when creating your database of valid tags.
   - You can't auto-start your app based on a specific ID.
   - You have to record every allowed ID in some database and can't easily define a large set of allowed tags.
2. You could use a specific NDEF record on the tag. In my opinion this is the prefered way to go.

   I would refrain from using the Text record type (or text/* MIME type records) as these types are supposed to be used to transport human-readable and (more importantly) human-interpreted *text*.

   Instead, I would suggest that you define your own NFC Forum external type name (specifications are available for free from NFC Forum) and create a record using that type name.

   - This allows you to easily auto-start your (and only your) app by filtering for that particular type name.
   - You can start the countdown based on either presence of an NDEF record with that particular type name, or
   - you can add a specific data payload to your tags (e.g. an custom identifier) to allow only certain tags that have this type name to start the countdown or to distinguish between different tags carrying a record with that type name.

---

For the ID matching scenario, I would suggest that you modify the foreground dispatch activation like this (*don't forget to actually activate the foreground dispatch in `onResume()`*):

```
public static void requestForegroundDispatch(final Activity act, NfcAdapter adp) {
    final Intent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(act, 0, new Intent(act, act.getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);

    IntentFilter[] filters = new IntentFilter[] { new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED) };
    String[][] techList = new String[][] { new String[] { NfcA.class.getName() } };

    adp.enableForegroundDispatch(act, pendingIntent, filters, techList);
}
```

This will match any ISO 14443 Type A tag (like the NTAG203).

Then you could retrieve the tag's ID in your handleIntent method like this:

```
private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
        Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
        byte[] id = tag.getId();

        // do something with the ID
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. This is for a private project using all of the same NTAG203 (NXP) NFC model. I do not have a large number of them to record, I don't need to autostart my app and it appears that as all of my tags are the same, the ID numbers will all be the same length. How would you implement the first approach?

Comment: So I thought I would be able to get it from here but I'm getting an incompatible type error under the handleIntent action with this: if (NfcV.get(tag) = 8434472A048A04)

Comment: I realized I'm just reading the byte array! Can anyone make a recommendation on how to use the ID to initiate some code? The NFC ID has numerals and letters...

Comment: The UID does not really consist of numeral and letters. Basically it's a string of bits (zeros and ones). One representation is to group it into groups of 8 bits. That's a byte array then. If you want to, for instance, translate these bytes into hexadecimal digits, this will give you two hexadecimal digits (a number between 00 and FF) for each byte. So to summarize this, you need to convert that byte array into whatever representation you want to have.